# clearing old kernels has left black screen after login ubuntu 14.04 lts - help

Tags: boot, grub2, kernel

If I have removed files unwittingly in a clear up of old kernels can I reinstall Grub or do something to recover my desktop ubuntu 14.04 gnome?

Following instructions on how to clear out older kernels by marking and removing completely I am now in a position where I start the computer, the screensaver comes up with the login space.  I click in the logic space and after a few moments the screen goes black and there is no response with keys or mouse.

I can get access to the GNU GRUB  version 2.02 beta2-9ubuntu1.4 menu by starting the computer and choosing 'Advanced options for Ubuntu'

There are additional options below which are Memory test (memtest86+) and Memory test (memtest86+, serial console 115200) and Microsoft Windows XP Home Edition (on /dev/sda1)

I then go to the advanced options for Ubuntu, check the remaining kernels, both original and recovery ones which are 3.13.0-67-generic.  I press 'e' and get the following info.  The difference between the recovery mode and the original kernel is the third line gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode which is missing in all the recovery modes.

Also, the 
linux   /boot/vmlinuz line ends in quiet splash $vt_handoff in the original and I have changed the recovery one to ro recovery nomodeset as suggested by someone.  It has made no difference to the performance.

I don't know if I removed some image or header or whatever files unknowingly.  I have no idea what I am doing really.  Trying to follow expert tips and suggestions on askubuntu.com

This is what I get in the Grub menu

```
setparams 'Ubuntu, with Linux 3.13.0-67-generic

recordfail
load_video
gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
insmod gzio
insmod part_msdos
insmod ext2
set root='hd0,msdos5'
if [ x$ feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
search --no-floppy -- fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos5 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos5 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos5  ede35015-e696-4a57\-8a1a-73ac7135e788
else 
 search --no-floppy --fs-uuid  --set=root ede35015-e696-4a57-8a1a-73ac7135e788 
fi
echo    'Loading Linux 3.13.0-67-generic ...'
linux     /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-67-generic root=UUID=ede35015-e696-4a57-8a1a-73ac7135e788 ro  quiet splash $vt_handoff
echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
initrd     /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0.67-generic

setparams 'Ubuntu, with Linux 3.13.0-67-generic (recovery mode)'

recordfail
load_video
insmod gzio
insmod part_msdos
insmod ext2
set root=hd0,msdos5'
if [ x$feature_platform_search-hint = xy ];  then
 search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos5 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos5 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos5  ede35015-e696-4a57\-8a1a-73ac7135e788
else
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root ede35015-e696-4a57-8a1a-73ac7135e788
fi
echo    'Loading Linux 3.13.0-67-generic ...'
linux     /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-67-generic root=UUID=ede35015-e696-4a57-8a1a-73ac7135e788 ro recovery nomodeset
echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
initrd    /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-67-generic
```

What can I do to get back into my ubuntu desktop?

Comment: Did you try changeroot into the system from a live cd?